# How do I do string separation in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

```xml
<xsl:when test="$patientRole/n1:id/@assigningAuthorityName">
                                                                                                                        
     <xsl:value-of select="$patientRole/n1:id/@assigningAuthorityName" />                                               
                                                  
</xsl:when>
```

I get this `Intergy Patient Number Intergy Patient ID SSN` like a text.

How can I separate that to look like:

```
Intergy patient Number
intergy patient ID
SSN
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to do something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$patientRole/n1:id/@assigningAuthorityName" separator="&#10;"/>
```

But this assumes that the spaces are there because the expression selects multiple nodes, not because they are in the original XML value/s. And it also assumes you want a textual output, not HTML or something that requires a different line break.

Comment: thanks for your answer@michael.hor257k but am looking  for a way to loop through the content of select="$patientRole/n1:id/@assigningAuthorityName". I didcovered they is no array in xsl but i need a way to dynamically get the contents.

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea what you mean by that. Please edit your question and add a [mcve] showing an example of the input.

Comment: My guess: the xpath returns several nodes, at the moment the `xsl:value-of` concatenates their string value, OP wants to process them one by one.

Comment: @lfurini At then moment, the `xsl:value-of` breaks them up into separate lines - as requested. Anyway, I am not into guessing.

Comment: @michael.hor257K thanks for your consistent contribution sir. I tried adding  the seperator= "&#10;" as you gave in the above solution so every output can start  on a new line but It didn't work I still got the old answer where all my outputs were placed in one line so I tried :  xsl:variable name ="stask" select="patientRole/n1:id/@assigningAuthorityName".   xsl:value-of  select="$stask[1]"<br></br>xsl-value-of select="$stask[2]"<br></br>xsl:value-of select= "$stask[3]" and it worked but how do I make it dynamic, without hardcoding it.

Comment: @HumpheryNwachukwu Please do not post code i comments. Edit your question and add a [mcve] showing an example input your current XSLT and the expected result. Without it, this is not going anywhere. Your saying "it didn't work" is not providing any useful information.